# Passing multiple columns to a function in R

Tags: r

So, I have a file (of about 500 rows) like this.

```
        V1    V2  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2       171   192 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
31       72   469 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0  0
32       72   327 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0  0
34       66   443 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  1
50      747   353 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
53      476   443 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
57     1259  1260 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  0
66      575   571 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0  0
84      407  1645 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0  0
87      120  1067 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
90      871   280 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0
95     1862  1656 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
......................................
```

I have a function which accepts the string such as "110100101010". Now, what I want to do is pass the numbers in the columns [1-10] of each row to that function.

Example: Function will first be applied to the first row, column [1-10]. Then it will be applied to second row, columns[1-10].......till the last row, column[1-10]. What I mean is that for every row, the numbers in columns[1-10] will be treated as string that the function accepts.

How can I write it in R?

Comment: Do `for`-loop, `apply(df, 1, ...)`, or `lapply(1:nrow(df), ...)`, etc. in tandem with `paste`. There are lots of relevant questions that do precisely this.

Answer (score 1):

Could do (as you suggested in comment) to create an additional column of your cols 3:12 and then apply your function on it

If your data called `data` and function called `f`, then

```
data$pattern <- apply(data[, 3:12], 1, paste, collapse = "")
sapply(data$pattern, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if let `df` be your `data.frame` and `col` a column of your `data.frame` and `foo` your function then you can do this:

```
foo(cat(df$col, sep=""))
```

and to do this more programmatically you can do this:

```
cols <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
apply(df[ , cols], MARGIN=1,
       FUN=function(x){
           foo(cat(x, sep=""))
       })
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Because my function is basically used for finding patterns and it for that, it iterates over taking in values of different length. Therefore, it shows an error. A possible solution to this would be to first convert the entire file so that the third column contains the string for each row and then applying the function to only that column for the file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying at all.

Comment: Check my edit.  I think I know what you're saying now, but not sure at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like...

```
bunnies <- as.vector(t(mydata[3:12]))
paste(bunnies, collapse = '')
```

I used this for a similar problem and it works perfectly.  I'm assuming your function can take all the row values at once, if not then you can write a function to loop through each row one by one and run this operation.